# Building older GLIBC on newer system

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, glibc

I have a question and I hope some guru here could help me out :) My goal is simple : (GOAL1) build a older glibc on a newer system and (GOAL2) build old software that can run on older glibc. I am on gcc4.9, glibc2.19, amd64 system. I did compile glibc2.14 and gcc4.7.3 on my system.

(convention : `/path/to/libc2.14_dir = $LIBC214`, /`path/to/gcc4.7.3 = $GCC473`)

I am trying to compile `bash4.2.53` ( and other softwares coreutil, binutil, qt3.3...) using newly built glibc2.14. My configure and make looks like this : ( I am being in object/build directory )

```
$ cd /path/to/build/bash-4.2.53
$ CC=$GCC473/bin/gcc CXX=$GCC473/bin/g++ CPP=$GCC473/bin/cpp \
   /path/to/source/bash-4.2.53/configure \
   --prefix=/path/to/installation/bash-4.2.53
$ make all V=1 \
   CFLAGS="-Wl,--rpath=$LIBC214/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=$LIBC214/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" \
   CPPFLAGS="-Wl,--rpath=$LIBC214/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=$LIBC214/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" \
   CXXFLAGS="-Wl,--rpath=$LIBC214/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker=$LIBC214/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
```

When make is done in bash4.2.53 build (object) directory, I tried 2 scenarios :

**SCENARIO1. Use system's libc2.19**

```
$ ldd ./bash
   linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe677c3000)
   libtinfo.so.5 => $MY_PREBUILT_NCURSE/lib/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f5d108e3000)
   libdl.so.2 => $LIBC214/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5d106df000)
   libc.so.6 => $LIBC214/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5d10354000)
   $LIBC214/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5d10b0a000)
```

**This line is weird :**`$LIBC214/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5d10b0a000)`

```
$ $LIBC214/bin/ldd ./bash
   not a dynamic executable
```

**SCENARIO2. Add $LIBC214/bin to my PATH, $LIBC214/lib to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH**

```
$ ldd ./bash
/bin/bash: $LIBC214/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /bin/bash)
$ export SHELL=$PWD/bash
$ ldd --version
/bin/bash: $LIBC214/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /bin/bash)
$ ldd ./bash
/bin/bash: $LIBC214/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /bin/bash)
```

As far as I can tell, SCENARIO2 is the right way to run commands. My assumption is that I built glibc2.14 wrongly, that it uses `/bin/bash` which in turn uses glibc2.19. I am not really sure.

My question:

1. Could you please explain for me the **weird line** above and the following line that out put **`not a dynamic executable`**?
2. Could you share me your steps to properly build glibc (GOAL1) and build software using that glibc (GOAL2) ?
3. What could I do next to solve 2 above scenario?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

when you link ELFs, the absolute path to the ldso is hardcoded in it.  if you want to use a different one, you can use the [`-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/path/to/ldso`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.26/ld/Options.html) flag to override it.  this path is absolute though, so if you try to move your local glibc somewhere else, the ELFs you linked will fail to execute (with errors like `no such file`).  there's no way around this as the system, by design, must have an absolute path in it to the [interpreter](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html).

the reason you get weird `not a dynamic executable` output is that `ldd` works by actually executing the target ELF and extracting (via debug hooks) the libraries that get loaded.  so when you attempt to use a diff `ldd` like that, glibc gets confused.  if you want a stable dependency lister, you might consider something like `lddtree` from the [pax-utils](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hardened/PaX_Utilities) project (most distros have this bundled nowadays).  or run `readelf -d` on the file directly and look at all the `DT_NEEDED` entries.

trying to build & maintain your own toolchain (glibc, gcc, etc...) is a huge hassle.  unless you want to dedicate a lot of time to this, you really should use a project like [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) to manage it for you.  that will allow you to build a full toolchain using an older glibc, and then you can use that to build whatever random packages you like.

if you really really want to spend time doing this all by hand, you should refer to the [glibc wiki](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/) for [building your own glibc](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Testing/Builds) and then [linking apps against that glibc](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Tips_and_Tricks/How_to_Build_an_application_with_your_own_custom_glibc).

Comment: 1st para : I actually did in my `$make above`. 3rd+4th para : I actually did spend ~ 50++ hours on this. Saw crosstool-ng along the way. I will have a look.  Thank you. Ah one more question. I found Gentoo Prefix. Do you recommend it over crosstool-ng or not ?

Comment: Gentoo Prefix generally uses the pre-existing host toolchain rather than building its own set of cross-compilers.  but if you made one with crosstool-ng, you might have luck making Gentoo Prefix use that toolchain.